# Why do I get this error while running factor() on a column of a data.frame

Tags: r

I am trying to run the command `factor(mydata$finding)` on my data.frame.

These are the contents of the column in my data.frame

[image]

I keep getting this error..

> Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
>
> Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Why do I get this?
and how do I get the levels in the column I have?

**data**

`str(mydata$finding)` gives this

```
List of 1290 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx, Prepyloric.Infillamatation" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx, Prepyloric.Infillamatation" 
$ : chr "Gastric.Bx, Gastric.Infillamatation" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx, Prepyloric.Infillamatation" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx, Prepyloric.Ulcer, Prepyloric.Infillamatation" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx, Prepyloric.Ulcer, Prepyloric.Infillamatation" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx" 
$ : chr "Prepyloric.Bx, Prepyloric.Infillamatation"
```

Comment: okay, so your data is a list, rather than a character vector. Try using `unlist` .. so `factor(unlist(mydata$finding))`. Note this assumes there is only each list element is of length one (which your looks like)

Comment: you're welcome. I find `str` a very useful function, and always use it after reading in data or creating some objects. I would also look back to your code to see how you ended up with this structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column was created using dplyr's mutate() function by adding a list()

Thus the column was read as list()

to solve it..

```
mydata$finding<-unlist(mydata$finding)
factor(mydata$finding)
```

Now works
Credits to @User20650 for the solution